# unable to resize textarea based on resizing a div

Tags: jquery, css

i have a textarea

```
<textarea name="quotes" id="resizeable" cols="40" rows="10" ></textarea>
```

i want to resize it from a div just below of the textaea.

`<div id="grippie" style="margin-right: 0px;cursor: n-resize;">-----------------------------</div>`

I tried the following script but its not resizing. What could be the reason? Please help me to solve this issue.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#grippie" ).resizable({
      alsoResize: "#resizeable"
    });
    $( "#resizeable" ).resizable();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Don't see any `#grippie` in HTML nor `#also` in Jquery?

Comment: @Aquillo Sorry, i updated it now. Please have a look

Comment: @SRamanujam Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nTnaU/.

Comment: @Eli I was trying like this http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/vqQQw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/vqQQw/2/

```
$('#resizable').resizable({
    handles: {
        s: $('.ui-resizable-s')
    },
    alsoResize: $('textarea')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what you are trying to achieve. `#grippie` is not referenced in your example HTML and also your DIV has a **class** of `resizeable` when your jQuery is referencing  **ID** `resizeable`.

Are you looking to achieve something [like this](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)?

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of trying but I got it to work.  As was already mentioned, your resizeable class should have been an ID and you were referencing grippie, which didn't exist.  In addition, you also need to reference the jQuery UI stylesheet or otherwise style the "handles" that are automatically added when you call resizable.  Note that they also add the appropriate cursor for you, so you don't have to style that yourself.

I have created a working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aRSs3/1/.

Here is the code:

**Markup:**

```
<div id="resizeable">Test</div>
<div id="grippie">Drag me</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#grippie").resizable({
        alsoResize: "#resizeable"
    });

    $('#resizeable').resizable();

});
```

**CSS:**

```
#resizeable {
    background:#EEE;
    width:180px;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px;
}
#grippie {
    background:#CCC;
    width:180px;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry ,But i want to resize my texarea you have implemented  for a div .Is it possibl to resize texarea from `#grippie` div.   Eg. In stackoverflow while posting question, one textarea appears, where user can draga a a div on its buttom to enlarge the textarea